# Covariance of the difference of two gaussian random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, covariance, dirac-delta

Suppose I have a random gaussian vector $\xi=[\xi_{1}(t),\xi_{2}(t),\xi_{3}(t)]^{T}$ with zero mean $\left(\textbf{E}\left(\xi_{1}(t)\right)=\textbf{E}\left(\xi_{2}(t)\right)=\textbf{E}\left(\xi_{3}(t)\right)=0\right)$ and that the covariances of each $\xi$ are delta-correlated. Namely

$$
\textbf{E}(\xi_{i}(t)\xi_{j}^{*}(t^{\prime})) = \delta_{ij}\delta(t-t^{\prime})
$$

where the elements of $\xi$ can be complex numbers. If I define $Y$ such that $Y_{j}=\xi_{j}-\xi_{j-1}$, how can I calculate the covariance of $Y$? Is it also true that

$$
\textbf{E}(Y_{i}(t)Y_{j}^{*}(t^{\prime})) = \delta_{ij}\delta(t-t^{\prime})
$$

?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

The covariance of $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ is

$$\begin{align}
\text{Cov}\left(Y_i(t),Y_j(t')\right)&=\text{Cov}\left(\xi_i(t)-\xi_{i-1}(t),\xi_j(t')-\xi_{j-1}(t')\right)\\\\
&=\text{Cov}\left(\xi_i(t),\xi_j(t')\right)-\text{Cov}\left(\xi_{i-1}(t),\xi_j(t')\right)\\\\
&-\text{Cov}\left(\xi_i(t),\xi_{j-1}(t')\right)+\text{Cov}\left(\xi_{j-1}(t),\xi_{j-1}(t')\right)\\\\
&=\left(\delta_{i,j}-\delta_{i-1,j}-\delta_{i,j-1}+\delta_{i-1,j-1}\right)\delta(t-t')\\\\
&=(2\delta_{i,j}-\delta_{i,j-1}-\delta_{i-1,j})\delta(t-t')\\\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: @kowalski Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.